# Restrict users from deleting enterprise apps in iOS

Tags: ios, app-store

We have an enterprise app store for our company where we deploy our iOS enterprise apps. I have a requirement to restrict the deletion of apps installed from the enterprise app store but the users can install and delete all the other apps downloaded from apple app store. Is there any way to do this. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: This has less to do with software development, but more with system administration. 
You will have to look at [MDM](http://www.apple.com/nl/support/business/mdm/), with which you can restrict device.

Comment: Using MDM in my device makes sure that I am not able to delete any app in my device, but I want to be able to delete the apple app store installed apps.